# How do I extract the contents of a partition backup done with dd?

Tags: dd, extract

I did a partition backup using dd and produced a .bin file.

How do I extract the contents of it? I would like to extract the contents to a folder say ~/Test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount it and access it as normal:

```
sudo mount -o ro,loop backup.bin /mnt
```

The files will appear in /mnt.